# Process all files in the directory

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I need to process all existing files in the directory, as well as process new files.

**In my implementation, between processing all the files and creating Watcher, a new file may appear that will remain unprocessed, how can this be fixed?**

```
            var dirPath = "myDir";
            while (true)
            {
                var alreadyExistFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dirPath);
                if (alreadyExistFiles.Count() == 0)
                    break;
                foreach (var file in alreadyExistFiles)
                    Process(file);
            }
            var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(dirPath);
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            watcher.Created += Watcher_Created;
```

Comment: Why not leave the new files alone/process them the next time you scoop?

Comment: The program can be run once for a very long time, and it must process files in a timely manner

Comment: What, you don't do anything that processes repeatedly ?

Comment: If use repetitions for the sake of this workaround, this solution does not look appropriate

Answer (score 1):

By creating list of processed files you can process new files as they come and avoid re-processing, code would be something like this:

```
var watcherRoot = @"C:\File path goes here";

var processedFiles = new List<string>();

var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(watcherRoot);
        
watcher.Created += (object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (ProcessFile(e.FullPath))
    {
        processedFiles.Add(e.FullPath);
    }
};

watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(watcherRoot))
{
    if (!processedFiles.Any(f => f == file))
    {
        ProcessFile(file);
    }
}
```

I would also use CancellationToken if processing is long and you plan to use asynchronous approach.

ProcessFile method should return boolean.

Comment: Thanks Can we opt out of using the processedFiles list? If the program is running for a long time, the sheet will be large and will eat up memory

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, it seems to me that the best solution is:
(+ add support for the cancellation token)

```
while(true)
{
    foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(watcherRoot))
    {
        ProcessFile(file);
    }
    await Task.Delay(500);
}
```

Comment: I can delete files during processing, the main problem is the synchronization of watcher and existing files

Comment: Ok, having read the code of this answer (before I just read the text "add a cancellation token") it seems to be exactly what I proposed in my answer, except your timer fires every 500 ms and doesn't try to ensure the file has finished being created ..

Comment: Honestly, FSW is great and useful and all but it doesn't mean it's suited to every problem. It can be made to work here but to what end? It fires events as soon as it sees a file created, which often means, if you react immediately to the event, you process the file before it's finished being written to.. so you still need a mechanism to ensure for that.. in certain situations it doesn't raise all events so you still need some process to sweep up stray files,, and eventually you settle on some hybrid with a timer and a FSW and patch in the existing files bit... all so complex. Go simple

Comment: (Not saying never use FSW, just that in this app it doesn't seem necessary)

Answer (score 1):

I think I would not bother to use a FileSystemWatcher, I would just have

- a timer that fires every 30 seconds
- tick event looks for all *.txt (for example) files in the directory
- try to puts them into a dictionary together with their current size (Key: file path, Value: size)

  - if the file is already in the dictionary look at the current size of the file on disk vs in dictionary:

    - if it has not changed then process the file, rename the file to *.done and remove it from the dictionary
    - if the size has changed update the dictionary with the new size
  - if the file is not in the dictionary put it in with the current size

File system watcher is hard work sometimes because it will raise an event while a file is still being written to, so you might process an incomplete file, if it's not locked for reading by the program writing it

By just having a regular timer process all the files you make sure to catch every one eventually

By renaming the files to "done" you don't process them twice but you can manually cause the reprocessing of an old file by renaming it back to TXT

The renaming could alternatively be "move to another folder" etc

By renaming/moving you use the filesytem to remember "which files are done" which doesn't eat up memory in your program and means your program can be restarted and still know which files are done

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode;

```
List<File> newFiles = new List<File>();
var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Created += (File newfile) => newFiles.Add(newFile)
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
foreach(File existingFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles())
{
   if(!newFiles.Contains(existingFile))
      processFile(existingFile);
}
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
foreach(File newFile in newFiles)
{
   processFile(newFile);
}
```

Comment: This way we can process one file twice if it was created after running watcher but before getting EnumerableFiles

Comment: Fair enough - edited the answer to add a check for this eventuality.